# Formato condicional con base en los valores de otra hoja en hojas de cálculo de Google

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas, formato-condicional

Tengo una hoja de cálculo de Google con dos hojas. En una de ellas deseo aplicar formato condicional con base en los valores de la otra hoja pero al intentar aplicar una fórmula personalizada, Hojas de Cálculo de Google me muestra un mensaje de error indicando que no es posible hacer referencia a hojas distintas.

Comment: Esta pregunta es una adaptación de algunas preguntas con respuesta que encontré en [so], por ejemplo, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36002062/1595451. Luego volveré para publicar una respuesta si es que nadie ha publicado la que tengo en mente.

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993416/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al aplicar formato condicional "las fórmulas solo pueden hacer referencia a la misma hoja mediante el uso de la notación estándar `(='nombrehoja'!celda)`. Para hacer referencia a otra hoja en la fórmula, usa la función `INDIRECT`."

```
=INDIRECT("Hoja2!A1")>0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencia**

[Aplicar reglas de formato condicional](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

## En breve

Las reglas de formato condicional en las hojas de cálculo de Google no permiten hacer referencia a otras hojas. Cuando se requiere esto usar INDIRECTO / INDIRECT.

## Explicación

INDIRECTO utiliza una cadena como parámetro de entrada y toma esta para devolver el valor de la referencia.

INDIRECTO tiene dos modos, uno que usa notación A1 y el otro usa la notación R1C1.

El uso de la notación R1C1 tiene como ventaja que se pueden construir referencias dinámicas utilizando variables numéricas para los índices de renglones y columnas.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente fórmula utiliza FILA() y COLUMNA() para determinar los índices de renglones y columnas lo cuál hace que la misma fórmula personalizada se pueda aplicar a varias celdas especificadas por un único rango.

```
=INDIRECTO("'Hoja 1'!R"&FILA()&"C"&COLUMNA(),FALSO)<>B2
```

[image: Regla de formato condicional]

## Referencias

- [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002062/1595451) publicada por mí a [Compare the values in two Google worksheets in the same document - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35993416/1595451)
- [Aplicar reglas de formato condicional - Ayuda de Editores de Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=es)